independence with respect to the sum of independent random variables
Assume we have $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are jointly independent random variables. Next, assume that
$$
X = X_{1} + X_{2} + X_{3}
$$
and $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$ are jointly independent. Does it follow that
$X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $X_{3}$, $Y$ and $Z$ are jointly independent?

In general, $X,Y$ independents, $X,Z$ independents and $Y,Z$ independents doesn't implies that $X,Y,Z$ independents.

I updated the question. $X$, $Y$, $Z$ are jointly independent and $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$, $X_{3}$ are jointly independent

No. For simplicity I'll set $X_3 = Z = 0$. So the question is: suppose $X_1, X_2, Y$ are random variables such that

$X_1, X_2$ are independent, and
$X = X_1 + X_2$ and $Y$ are independent.

Then are $X_1, X_2, Y$ jointly independent?
Assume for simplicity that $X_1, X_2, Y$ are jointly Gaussian. Then they are jointly independent iff they are uncorrelated. Our hypotheses are equivalent to
$$\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = \text{Cov}(X_1 + X_2, Y) = 0$$
which gives $\text{Cov}(X_1, Y) = - \text{Cov}(X_2, Y)$, but it is possible for these covariances to be nonzero. A necessary and sufficient condition for a covariance matrix to be realizable as the covariance matrix of a joint Gaussian distribution is that it is positive semidefinite, so it suffices to find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that, for example, the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \varepsilon \\ 0 & 1 & - \varepsilon \\
 \varepsilon & -\varepsilon & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is positive semidefinite (where $\varepsilon = \text{Cov}(X_1, Y)$). But since it has eigenvalues $1, 1, 1$ at $\epsilon = 0$ this follows by continuity.
